# Keyboard shortcut for stopping all programs, which ran parallely?

Tags: python, linux, shell, parallel-processing

I am running two python scripts in parallel on linux using the following command

```
python program01.py & python program02.py
```

When I use a keyboard shortcut like 'ctrl+c' to stop them, it only closes the program which was last in the command (e.g. here it is 'program02.py'), and the other one stays open/running.

I need to know how can I close all of them at a time using a keyboard command, as I need all of them to keep running sometimes, when only keyboard command will be possible to use.

Comment: I always make a separate dummy thread that looks for any keypress, and terminates the program.  Control-C doesn't always work.  Don't know if that would work for two programs at once though.

Comment: Could you please give example, about how would you make separate dummy thread regarding that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run program with `&` at end, it runs in background. To kill all background jobs, use `jobs -p | xargs kill -9` command. There is no bash shortcut for that.

In that case, you may want to run your command as:

```
python program01.py & python program02.py &
```

Comment: Defaulting to `-9` is a bad idea. It should only be used if the process doesn't respond to sigterm.

Comment: Although this method works, but still I would like to know, why/how -9 is a bad idea?

Comment: `-9` kills application immediately without giving a chance to respond, save files or what application is supposed to do upon exit.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such shortcut, but you can make some:

```
trap 'kill -INT $(jobs -p) &> /dev/null' INT
```

With this in your `.bashrc`, Ctrl+C on a command line will interrupt all background jobs.

That means you can hit Ctrl+C to kill the foreground process, and then Ctrl+C again to kill any background processes.

Alternatively,

```
bind '"\C-b": "\nkill $(jobs -p)\n"'
```

will let you use Ctrl+B to kill all background jobs, so that you won't do it by accident when frantically hitting Ctrl+C to kill a foreground process.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code to start a dummy thread and will break out of any loop when the dummy thread detects any keyboard input.  I have found this to be a reliable way to stop a program when control-C doesn't work, but I'm sure there are better solutions.

```
import thread
def input_thread(L):
    raw_input()
    L.append(None)
dummykeypress = []
thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, (dummykeypress,))
while True:
    if dummykeypress: break  # or exit() to kill entire program, etc
```